# Assign Primary Key of Table 1 as a Foreign Key in Table 2 using SQL and C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have tables Member and Office which use an auto-increment primary key, Member_Id and Office_Id. I am inserting data into the tables but would like to have primary key of the Member table inserted on the Office Table as a foreign key, so that a member is assigned to an office record.  Please assist.  Below is a snippet of my code for inserting the records but I just do not know how to link the two tables.

```
protected void capture()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter();

            com.CommandText = "INSERT into Member(Appointment_Number, Initials, Surname, Designation) VALUES (@Appointment_Number, @Initials, @Surname, @Designation)";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appointment_Number", txtAppointmentNumber.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initials", txtInitials.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", ddlDesignation.Text);              
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Parameters.Clear();

           //Insert records into the office table                
            com.CommandText = "INSERT into Offices(Office_Number, Status, Building, Branch, Floor) VALUES (@Office_Number, @Status, @Building, @Branch, @Floor)";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office_Number", txtOffNo.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ddlOStatus.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", ddlBuilding.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", ddlBranch.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Floor", ddlFloors.Text);               
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Parameters.Clear();               

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/MemberDetails.aspx");

            }
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Excuse me, but the relationships seems to be: An _Office_ has zero to N _Member_. Right? Then it is the **Member** table that needs an **OfficeID** Foreign Key not the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you want to set a relation between offices and members 1 to n.

So to do that, lets add officeid field in members table, insert the office record before the member and change the code like this;

```
protected void capture()
    {
        string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDatabase"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter();

            //Insert records into the office table                
            com.CommandText = "INSERT into Offices(Office_Number, Status, Building, Branch, Floor) VALUES (@Office_Number, @Status, @Building, @Branch, @Floor)";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Office_Number", txtOffNo.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", ddlOStatus.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Building", ddlBuilding.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Branch", ddlBranch.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Floor", ddlFloors.Text);
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Parameters.Clear();

            com.CommandText = "select max(Office_Id) from Offices";
            int officeid = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());

            com.CommandText = "INSERT into Member(officeid,Appointment_Number, Initials, Surname, Designation) VALUES (@officeid,@Appointment_Number, @Initials, @Surname, @Designation)";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@officeid", officeid);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Appointment_Number", txtAppointmentNumber.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Initials", txtInitials.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", txtSurname.Text);
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", ddlDesignation.Text);
            com.Connection = conn;
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            com.Parameters.Clear();

            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                Response.Redirect("~/Pages/MemberDetails.aspx");

            }
        }        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've inserted into your first table, using the same connection, `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get the auto-assigned identity value just created. You can then use that to insert into the second table.

Using SCOPE_IDENTITY() will ensure that you always get the id that you just created. If your system is being used by multiple users concurrently, you don't want to risk picking up the identity value created by another user that happened to be inserting data at the same time as you.

e.g. after your first insert:

```
com.CommandText = "SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
int my_id_just_created = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: I have just used the above command after inserting to the first table but it gives a System.InvalidCastException error that says "Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types".

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is probably to insert your `Office` table first, get the scope identity, and put that in the FK of you `member` insert. To get the scope identity just use this syntax :

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
(val1, val2, val3 ...)
VALUES(@val1, @val2, @val3...);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Then you use `com.ExecuteScalar()` that will return you an Int with the PK of the `Office` table that you can use as the FK of the `Member` table.